# fullcalendar.js how to display a current day +4 days in advance and -2 days behind in week view

Tags: javascript, view, fullcalendar

Just read the documentation about the full calendar, but still can't find how to show a calendar that shows only a week with two days behind the current day and four days after the current day.

So the current day in a week view would always be the third day.

If there is out of the box solution, please feel free to share it. Otherwise I am looking to develop the plugin.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you simply have to change the `firstDay` to your current date minus two days and do that everyday.

here is the [doc](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/firstDay/) for that property.

Comment: By some reason the best solutions are easy ones :)